# Change the width of all lines in a PDF programmatically

Tags: perl, pdf

I made handwritten slides using an iPad app, and found out that the line was too thin to be projected on a big screen in a room.

Unfortunately that app doesn't have the ability to change the stroke widths afterwards... (geez.) But I have the exported PDF file.

As a programmer I should be able to solve my problem programmatically, by
changing the width of all lines on a PDF by, say, a factor of two.

So, my question is what would be the easiest way to achieve my objective.
Is there a Perl module which allows me to inspect all the lines on a PDF, for example?

-- Update

OK, I converted the PDF to a PS file via `ps2pdf` (which uses Ghostscript), and replaced  `3 w` by `6 w` etc. using my text editor. (here `w` is a macro expanding to `setlinewidth`.) Then I converted the resulting PS file back to a PDF. Problem solved.

But is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Inkscape to convert the .pdf into .svg, parse it with some script (Python, for example, it doesn't matter), then convert it back to .pdf .
   If this isn't enough programmatic, a command line option is available:

```
>inkscape -l test.pdf output.svg
```

And back after processing:

```
>inkscape -l processed.svg final.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Is .svg better than using .ps as an intermediate textual representation? I don't know at all about .svg ...

Comment: I haven't used .ps, i don't know about it. .svg is quite self-explanatory, so it is easy to edit it through a script.

Comment: I see... .ps is quite self-explanatory, too.

Comment: Then I believe you can modify that with a script.

Comment: Yes that's what I did... (I used the regex replacement using an editor; I can do that with a script.) I was wondering if it's possible directly with PDF files...

Comment: I don't think it is. PDF's are not readable via normal text editors.