# Change a PDF's 0.00pt Lines to a Larger Size

Tags: pdf, line, render, ghostscript, postscript

In [this PDF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-FP75R12KT3-DS-v03_00-en_de.pdf?fileId=db3a304412b407950112b431719f544e), the drawings on the second-to-last page apparently use a 0.00pt line width. This makes them almost unreadable on-screen, and completely invisible when printed.

Is there a relatively painless way to change these "no width" lines to have **some** width?  There are lots of small details, so converting to image will not retain enough detail unless an outlandish resolution is used... then the "no width" issue re-emerges.

I've installed [GhostScript](https://www.ghostscript.com), ran `pdf2ps in.pdf med.ps` then `ps2pdf med.ps out.pdf` and the line weights are exactly the same. Next, I opened `med.ps` in a text editor, hoping I could make a python script "find and replace" these zero line widths, but I'm seeing nothing like "0 w" in the file. Perhaps it is defined in a macro somewhere, but I'm not seeing it.

This idea came from [Change the width of all lines in a PDF programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040958/change-the-width-of-all-lines-in-a-pdf-programmatically) and [Thicken line weights when printing PDF](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/thicken-line-weights-when-printing-PDF-q209321.aspx).

Comment: I was able to correct the thin lines (0.035pt apparently) by importing the page into [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org), opening the object, finding a relevant section by hiding object groups, shift-ctrl-F to show fill settings, then stroke style tab --> 0.2mm. But this can only output to a separate file, and for one page.

Answer (score 2):

Best bet is to use a tool to decompress the PDF file (eg, using MuPDF; `mutool -d <in.pdf> <out.pdf>` or with Ghostscript `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o out.pdf -dCompressPages=false in.pdf`) then use a text editor or some kind of scripting tool such as sed to look for "0 w" and replace wiith 'something else'.

PDF isn't a programming language, unlike PostScript, so you can reliably search for operator usage like this in a PDF file, trying to do the same in a PostScript file is, as beginner6789 says above, extremely hard.

If you want to then have the finak file compressed you could run the edited file through Ghostscript's pdfwrite device using something like `gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o final.pdf in.pdf`.

You absolutely should not use Ghostscript's ps2write device to producce PostScript; the PostScript imaging model is not entirely compatible with PDF, and any PDF constructs which cannot be represented in PostScript (such as any kind of transparency) will be rendered to an image. Really, don't do this.

Comment: I noticed that ps2write changed the output PDF slightly, so totally believe it could fail horribly. Your decompress idea is good... I decompressed the original, and could not find "0 w" but did find "0.146648 w" and "0.148345 w" using VS Code and an unvetted .PDF plugin. Changing these from Code "blacks out" all chart captions however, which I think might be due to corruption of binary data. Will try with a python (true binary parsing) approach soon.

Comment: Well that's not hairlines, true hairlines are one pixel wide on any device (no matter the resolution) and are defined as '0 w'. Of course, on a low resolution device a thin line could still be hard to see. I'm afraid that in this case it would be very hard to find a solution; the linewidth while small might be very variable. Changing it to a much larger number could result in surprisingly thick lines, I'd suggest increasing the numbers slowly (try doubling to start).

Answer (score 1):

This could be a problem if there are a lot of different weights used and you just want to change the 0.0 width lines. If they were all 0.0 then placing this early in the page could work unless the postscript looks in the system dictionaries for the command:

```
/setlinewidth {pop} def
```

The default linewidth for my ghostscript is 1.0 so that should be used automatically instead of the 0.0 linewidth.

The pdf2ps usually has a lot of pdf style dictionaries so finding the code used for setlinewidth can be confusing. The setlinewidth must be there someplace. Some people like to read postscript.

Pdf files aren't really meant to be edited so I use these options to make reading the final pdf easier: -dCompressPages=false -dCompressStreams=false just in case there is some useful information to look at in the pdf.

EDIT: depending on the code used to create the original postscript there might be labels like this:

```
dup/LW//knownget exec{
setlinewidth
}if

/w/setlinewidth load def
```

So there could be LW or w used for setlinewidth like this simple example. Most are not this simple.

EDIT2: There is some good info here:
[How to change the width of lines in a PDF/PostScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55464503/how-to-change-the-width-of-lines-in-a-pdf-postscript-file?rq=1)